# MySQL table design for products with expiration time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a store where I sell products with duration (expiration time for users).
I have a mysql table for users who look like this

```
| user_id | user_name | user_password | user_email |
```

and another one for products :

```
| product_id | product_name | product_price |
```

I'm selling two products, so now I'm wondering if should I add two columns in user table so it will look like this .

```
 | user_id | user_name | user_password | user_email | product_one | product_two |
```

and in those fields put the date of expiration for the users who already bought the products (both of them will be blank by default), 
or should I just make a new table for the purchased products and then store the appropriate `user_id`.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: and how will be verification hmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second choice is more like a 3NF (3rd Normal Form). I have some little experience in e-shops (mainly in Opencart) and in my opinion, and from whatever I've already seen, this is how they're working.

In fact, it's far better to have one more table which will hold the 'Orders' and a 'User_Id', and another table that will hold the 'Orders' and the 'Product_Ids' in them.

I'm neither a database nor an e-shop platform expert, but according to my experience, I'd go with the second one.

**EDIT**

I'm editing my current answer to add an example. So, you already have two tables, one for users (customers) and one for products. These two table are (as already mentioned) the following (I don't know the actual table names, so I'll put mine).

**table 'users':**

```
| user_id | user_name | user_password | user_email |
```

**table 'products':**

```
| product_id | product_name | product_price |
```

So, my suggestion is to introduce a new entity (let's name that entity 'order')  and create a table that will contains each order matched with the user that made it. So the **'orders' table** will be something like this:

```
| order_id | user_id |
```

Then you will have another table that will match each order with a product_id. In this table you can have also your 'expiration time' field. A sample of such table is the following:

**table 'order_products':**

```
| order_id | product_id | product_exp_date |
```

However, tha last table has a flaw: it has not a PRIMARY KEY. You have to be a little creative here and import a field in order to hold a primary key, such as `order_product_id`, which will hold a UNIQUE identifier for each separate product in each separate order. But you'll have to find a way on how to do this.

Hope this clarified my thought.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You want a separate table, which I will name users_products. This will allow you to add products. It's generally more flexible.

It will have these columns

```
 user_id    
 product_id
 expiration
```

You can find what current products a user possesses like this:

```
select u.user_name, u.user_email, p.product_name
  from users u
  left join users_products up on u.user_id = p.user_id
  left join products p  on up.product_id = p.product_id
                       and p.expiration >= NOW()
```

The primary key of your users_products table should be a compound key made of all three columns.

When you sell a user with ID 123 the product with id 321, expiring in 30 days, you represent that in your database with this query.

```
 INSERT INTO users_products
             (user_id, product_id, expiration)
      VALUES ( 123,       321,        NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```